# Bandwidth Quota Management Python

Tags: python, windows, proxy, bandwidth, squid

I've been playing around with a few proxying options at home lately, and I've come across a bit of a problem - I need to limit the bandwidth quota - So each computer is allowed 200MB download/upload a day. Is this possible? If so, how. If this is not possible with python (which I doubt), is there any free software that will do this for me? (Preferably with an API).

OS: Windows XP SP2/SP3
Proxy Software: Squid

I did look at [another related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9958891/bandwidth-quota-in-squid), but it wasn't of any use to me (I couldn't make head or tail of it...).

Comment: Excellent first question. However, I'm not sure why you want to use Python in the first place. Also, *free* is a loaded term. Do you mean free as in free beer or free speech? Also, I removed the [signature - we like our questions as plain as possible](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5029/are-taglines-signatures-disallowed)

Comment: @user1423431, this task would be substantially easier if you punted the Windows XP requirement and ran your proxy as a Linux [virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) inside XP.  At that point, the linux kernel offers a significant toolset for managing traffic

Comment: Thanks! I would do this, however, I am getting internet via a 3G modem, and as hard as I try to get the modem working with Ubuntu, I have no success.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps give [Squid Quota](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/squidquota/) a shot.

Comment: Thanks both for your answers! As in my definition of free software: Software in which I can download which is not maleware and does not have any obligation for me to pay money to the writers of the software. Also which by download is generaly not having any features taken out or no 30-day trial period - think of it as in the Student Version of Autodesk maya, you are free to download it and use it as long as you are a student, there are no limitations to it, except now and then it will just remind me to buy the full version, and there is no 30 day trial period.

Comment: I hit enter before I was finished - Still getting used to the interface ;). Why python? Because python is a freely avaliable, easyily understandable scripting language that can be used for a variety of purposes, and it is relavively fast. Mainly for the reason that I can whip together code quickly. @ Christian Witts: Thanks for your response, I'll check it out!